# ¿Cómo puedo hacer un query para insertar?

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

[image: Estructura de la BD]

Esta imagen muestra la estructura de mi base de datos, pero al intentar insertar un registro en consultas, no sé cómo relacionarlo con la tabla `historial`.

Explico la estructura, `Empresa` guarda nombres, los campos de alguna empresa, `Web` guarda los datos de algún usuario de alguna empresa, `historial` guarda los datos de inicio y cierre de sesión, `consultas` todo lo que ocurre en esa sesión. Cuando un usuario consulta algún producto, esto se debe guardar en la tabla `consultas` de acuerdo al `id` del `historial`, en una sesión un usuario puede hacer muchas consultas, la idea es asociar a la sesión las consultas pero no encuentro el *query* que haga eso.

Comment: Has probado con cookies? En la sesion los datos son efímeros, solo se guardan mientras tengas el navegador abierto, simplemente debes lanzar una consulta sql con el método post

Comment: Pero en la BD como se va a relacionar con el usuario de la session, el problema no es lanzar el sql si no cual seriá el sql correcto...

Comment: @Alberto: ¿Puedes compartir lo que has intentado? Porque ¿no se trata simplemente de hacer un `insert into Consultas (...) values (...)`? De seguro debe algo mas que te está trancando... tal vez al compartir lo que has intentado podremos entender cual es la complicación.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacer un insert y dentro una subconsulta que te obtenga el id consultas en cuestión.

```
INSERT INTO
  Consultas (id_historial, n...)
VALUES
  ( (SELECT id_historial
     FROM Historial AS H JOIN Web AS W
     ON H.id_web = W.id_web WHERE W.nombre_usuario = $_SESSION['nombre-usuario'] ))
```

Le agregas la sintaxis de acuerdo a lo que estés usando.

La lógica es:

1. Primero obtienes el id_historial según el usuario logeado cuya
   información está en la tabla Web (esto es la subconsulta).
2. Insertas en Consultas usando el id_historial que obtuviste en el
   paso anterior.

Answer (score 1):

Buenas, podrías hacer lo siguiente, si quieres mantener un control estricto podrías poner como **id web** la IP del cliente(

```
// Function to get the client IP address
function get_client_ip() {
    $ipaddress = '';
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED']))
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED'];
    else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR']))
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED']))
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED'];
    else if(isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']))
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    else
        $ipaddress = 'UNKNOWN';
    return $ipaddress;
}
```

);

El **id Historial** podría ser un número autoincrementable simplemente, de esta manera sabría que consultas has hecho en una misma sesión puesto que todas se agruparían en el mismo id autoincrementable...

Luego el **inicio y cierre sesión** serían un objeto Date, con un `new Date();` en el instante adecuado sería  suficiente.

Espero haber-te ayudado :D!

Ok respondiendo a tu comentario debes crear un **id de usuario** que será único para cada usuario! De ésta manera te aseguras que aunque se conecten a la vez pertenecen a registros diferentes :)

**id de usuario** aparecerá en web y será clave forana en historial y consultas..

Comment: En la tabla web el id_web ya es un identificador único para un usuario, y cada que se loguea o cierra sesion, se hace un registro con un new Date presisamente como lo indicas, en donde tengo problemas es para registrar la consulta, para que pertenezca a la sesion ya que dos usuarios podrian loguearse al mismo tiempo y lo unico que tendrian diferente es el id_historial y el id_web, pero no se  como saber a cual corresponde a cada usuario.

Answer (score 1):

Primero debes tener en cuenta que al loguearse en el sistema deberás crear variables de sesión para `id_web` y `id_historial`, el campo `inicioSession` se crea con la hora y la fecha actuales, `cierreSession` primero se insertará como un `NULL`. Ahora estos datos se insertan en la tabla `Historial`.

Bien, ahora cada que un usuario haga una consulta vas a utilizar el parámetro de sesión `id_historial`, el campo `id_consultas` deberá ser un auto incrementable con respecto al `id_historial` (es decir, debe ser una llave compuesta) y posteriormente también enviarás los demás campos que corresponden a la tabla `Consultas` para que tu `INSERT` en base de datos quede de la siguiente forma asumiendo que realizas el `INSERT` a través de un `Stored Procedure`

```
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertaConsultas
     @inIdHistorial INT
    ,@vcPlacaConsultada VARCHAR(256)
    ,@dtHoraConsultada  DATETIME
    ,@btExportarPDF     BIT
    ,@dtHoraExportacion DATETIME
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @inIdConsultas INT
    SET @inIdConsultas = 0

    SELECT @inIdConsultas = ISNULL(id_consultas, 0) + 1 FROM consultas
    WHERE id_historial = @inIdHistorial

    INSERT INTO [consultas]
                ([id_consultas]
                ,[id_historial]
                ,[PlacaConsultada]
                ,[HoraConsultada]
                ,[ExportarPDF]  
                ,[HoraExportacion])
            VALUES
                (@inIdConsultas
                ,@inIdHistorial
                ,@vcPlacaConsultada
                ,@dtHoraConsultada  
                ,@btExportarPDF     
                ,@dtHoraExportacion)

END
```

Finalmente, tendrás que manejar el cierre de sesión y enviar un `UPDATE` para que con la fecha y hora actuales se actualice el campo `cierreSession` y puedas tener la información completa en la tabla `Historial`

Answer (score 0):

Tendrías que agregar el campo id_web en la tabla 'consultas'. Tal como está, si 2 ó más usuarios inician sesión al mismo tiempo, como indicas en uno de tus comentarios, no tendrías forma de saber a quien pertenece la(s) consulta(s) realizada(s) en esa sesión. sakulino lo explica al final de su respuesta.